# Making d3.js compatible with IE8/IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, d3.js

I am using a Leaderboard from the following link

http://labs.juiceanalytics.com/leaderboard/index.html#2a65db98c6f451b7f071b630694bc350

In this leaderboard d3.js and d3.csv.js are being used.
This leaderboard is working fine for me in all the browsers except IE8 and IE9.
For these browsers some error in scriptting is there with d3.js.
I have searched it out well on internet but i didn't find any promising solution to make it work with IE8 or IE9.
The error which it is showing is that "Object can't find the .map() method", which is used in d3.js.
Glad if somebody can help me out in this.

Comment: see http://webmonarch.github.io/d34raphael/

Comment: and also https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3

Comment: FYI: that's the post where I found those links https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/619

Comment: The links in the above comments are all to dead projects.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The author of d3 [recommends](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) using [aight](https://github.com/shawnbot/aight) HTML5 shim/polyfill bundle for compatibility.

The .map method in question is part of EcmaScript5 - and therefore [not available in IE8](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map).

Mozilla provides [a function you can drop in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap) to get this functionality. Good luck with IE8!

Comment: Use `html5-shim` and `html5-sham` to get EcmaScript 5 functionality in IE8.