# Rendering a map on ie8 with D3

Tags: d3.js, internet-explorer-8, raphael

I know that D3 does not support IE8 but I'm hoping to find something that will work.

I am trying to use R2D3 https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3, but the map I am creating still isn't rendering.  With r2d2 loaded in the head of the page I have:

```
projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
  .scale(700)
  .translate([1000*0.3, 400*0.4])

path = d3.geo.path()

mapData = topojson.features(mapJSON, mapJSON.objects.states)

d3.select('svg')
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'states')
  .datum(mapData)
  .attr('d', path.projection(projection))
```

This renders fine in chrome but in ie8 it unsurprising does not work.

With r2d3 it renders

```
<svg width="675" height="290">
    <path class="states" __data__='[object object]' d="
</svg>
```

So it would appear that the callback of `path.projection(projection)` is not actually being executed or not returning anything. And thus braking the html.

Furthermore, I was under the impression that r2d3 would degrade to non-svg elements in ie8.

Anyone have experience in rendering a d3 map in ie8?

I've seen [Making d3.js compatible with IE8/IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828501/making-d3-js-compatible-with-ie8-ie9), https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/619 among many others.

Comment: I suggest showing a map image for IE8 instead of interactive visualization.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support svg, that only started with IE9. I don't know neither D3 nor r2d3, but what I can do for you is suggest to use http://raphaeljs.com/

It's an awesome JS library for many needs and it renders in IE8 VML instead of SVG, through browser detection.

If you need any help using RaphaelJS, comment on this answer with some more information about your map data and what you want to do with it.

Best Regards.