# What are invalid values when setting style properties in IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js

Im doing a js with D3v4 library. It works in Chrome, Firefox, IE edge and IE 10. But I need it works in IE 9.

I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828501/making-d3-js-compatible-with-ie8-ie9) but this is for the D3v3 version. Even so, I try solve my problem with the answer but don't work.

In IE9 the console report this type errors.

> SCRIPT87: Argumento no válido.
>
> Archivo: d3.min.js, Línea: 2, Columna: 6430

This error mark this function in d3.js library:

```
function styleConstant(name, value, priority) {
  return function() {
    this.style.setProperty(name, value, priority);
  };
}
```

Specifically this line:

```
this.style.setProperty(name, value, priority);
```

And if I usin d3.min.js mark this function:

```
function B(t,n,e){return function(){this.style.setProperty(t,n,e)}}
```

Specifically this line:

```
this.style.setProperty(t,n,e)
```

I found this [answer](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2519) and it says this:

> Yes, IE9 throws an error sometimes if you try to set an invalid style property. This is one of IE9’s quirks, and since D3 is not a compatibility layer, you’ll need to avoid invalid values when setting style properties.

But i don't know what are invalid values in style properties.

Comment: http://caniuse.com

Comment: What does caniuse.com have to do with this question?

Comment: OP can go at this place and look for compatibility for IE browsers ;)

Comment: @ReclutaPatoso, it depends on the property you're trying to set. You'll have to provide the actual arguments.

Comment: @ReclutaPatoso http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity for opacity settings in IE.

Comment: Where did OP used the word "opacity"?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i set a lot of properties in script...I cant know what are affecting becouse the report dont mark my script.

Comment: In that case, it's impossible to help you. There are lots and lots of properties, and it's almost impossible for anyone here at S.O. list all valid values. For example, if the property is `dominant-baseline`, the valid values are "auto | use-script | no-change | reset-size | ideographic | alphabetic | hanging | mathematical | central | middle | text-after-edge | text-before-edge | inherit". That's for **one** property only!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado maybe someone have a list of invalid properties or properties values in IE9. I have a hard work... T_T

Comment: That's impossible. For the example, above, "jhgvjhgjv" is an invalid value. I believe you're talking about a list of **valid** values. Which is also huge, by the way.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Uff... I go to cry a lot. I see for example, i cant use rgba property and Im using it. I comment it and now the error list is little, but i have a hard work to see more fails...

Comment: Now i need see all my script `style` atribute and check in http://caniuse.com it works or not in IE9

Comment: If you use a patched version of d3.js with a `console.log(t,n);` just in front of `this.style.setProperty(t,n,e)` you should see which property it was called on just before throwing an error. You‘d have to step through all properties that are failing one-by-one, though…

Comment: @undko thank you, nice idea.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
element.style("property", "value");
```

It's absolutely necessary that the value is **always** a string. Otherwise you will get a weird Character Error in IE9 as it can only handle strings.

I tested it with D3JS 4.10.12.